# Android SQLite, some SQL basics

Tags: android, database, sqlite, initialization, oncreate

I am following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx

I must be overthinking this SQLite stuff (in the past my domain server would automatically initialize databases I requested, and I could do queries when desired. never put one together from scratch)

I have some questions about their onCreate function. I never recall using a
`CREATE TRIGGER` command in my SQL

I only need to create one table with 2 or 3 columns (if you count the primary key)

I should just be able to do 
`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + tableName +"("+colID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+columnName+"TEXT)");`

correct?

Do I need a "Trigger" and a "View" ?

Comment: you don't need trigger and view for creating a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a place to store some data - then Table is enough. But if your logic is more complicated then you'll need additional stuff.
 Also note that some Triggers are not supported by SQLite: [Info from here](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)

Answer (score 1):

You not need to create TRIGGER. Unless it is required. Here is how I implemented in one of my project. Hope this help.

https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/provider/FeedDB.java

Comment: It will be great if you can rate the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need a [Trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) or a [View](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html), then you do not need to create them.  It appears that the tutorial is just explaining some of the things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

if SQLite `TRIGGER` and `VIEW` are similar to what they're used for in MySQL then no, they are not necessarily for what you're trying to accomplish.

`VIEW`s are useful when you have complex queries (like when using `JOIN`s to join data from multiple tables).

`TRIGGERS`s are conditions that are run when you modify a table. (like using `UPDATE`, or `INSERT`)

Answer (score 0):

As written, your create statement won't work because of a lack of whitespace. Try:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName +" (" + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + columnName + " TEXT)");
```

Comment: yes, I am being cautious of the syntax, but I am mainly emulating